# Using History.js for axax. Works great, but I am confused on what happens when user hits back to re-enter my app

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser-history, history.js, html5-history

I am using History.js and Jquery (and a little GWT), I use the History.pushState() method to store the Ajax payload, then in the statechanged event I paint the screen according to the payload. Now inside my app the browswer back and forward buttons work correctly.

The strange thing is when users click a link in my app that takes them to a page that is outside of my app (same domain but another application), they go out, view the page, then hit the back button to re-enter my app.

My app loads, it does not receive a popstate or a statechange event, but somehow the browser is actually painting the screen to resemble exactly what it looked like before they left my app.

I'd like to understand what is happening here.

[EDIT: I was wrong. My code was executing and I did receive the statechange. I had some assumptions about History.js, and now I realize to code correctly, you should receive your AJAX payload, then call pushstate to put it on the stack. Then your statechange event will fire, and you should, in the statechange function, read the state off the stack and paint the screen accordingly. The same code will execute when you run your app normally, and the same code will execute when the user hits the back button. ]

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the URL and then handle accordingly. It's the same as if you were deep linking into your application directly from the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the browser is showing a cached state of the app instead of completely reloading it when the user uses the back button to return to the app.

You can test this by going into the app, clicking the outside app link, hitting the browser back button to go back, and then hitting refresh. If it changes the app state upon reload, it tells you that the browser was caching the app state instead of reloading.